# MongoDB: Which permissions are needed for a user to create a database?

Tags: mongodb

We need to create a special role that will allow only the following actions:

1. Create a new database
2. Create a new user, which is admin for that database

Which MongoDB roles are needed to create a database? It is not written anywhere in the documentation here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/ and it doesn't seem there is a known role which can perform this task

Comment: [dbOwner](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#dbOwner)

Comment: Maybe `dbAdmin` or `readWrite` can be sufficient: you can check the full built-in roles list [here(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/)

Answer (score 0):

I think `readWrite` is the role you need.
I tried what follows:

1. connect to my `admin` db using an administrative user
2. create a new `aaa` user, defined on `admin` db, with a password and two roles: `readWrite` on (not existent) database `xxx` and `dbAdmin` on (not existent) database `yyy`
3. connect to the `admin` db using `aaa` user

So I tried to insert a document in a `test` collection in both `xxx` and `yyy` databases:

```
use xxx
db.test.insert({})
```

with response
*Inserted 1 record(s) in 2ms*

```
use yyy
db.test.insert({})
```

with response
*not authorized on yyy to execute command ...*

The error message refers to the fact that `aaa` can't execute `insert` into `test`: database creation happens at the time of the first insert, so you need `readWrite` role in order to make the first `insert` ==> create the database.

I hope the approach I adopted to check the question can help you resolving your problem.